# Find the directional derivative of the scalar field

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the directional derivative of the scalar field:

> $f(x,y,z)=\log(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ at $P_0(1,1,1)$ in the direction of the straight line $\ P_0P $  where $P=(3,2,1)$

What I have done: $\nabla(f)=(2/3,2/3,2/3)$ at $P_0$ and I know the eqation of $P_0P$ is

> $(x-1)/2=(y-1)/1=(z-1)/0=t(say)$

Now the required unit vector is $\frac{(3-1,2-1,1-1)}{\sqrt 5}$ taking dot product with $\nabla f$ my final result comes out to be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ . But the answer does not match.

Also my confusion arises seeing [this article](http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fmathinsight.org%2Fdirectional_derivative_gradient_examples&h=sAQFNNLfU). According to the article, answer comes out as $\frac{9}{\sqrt{14}}$ . But the answer given in my exercisebook is $\frac{8}{3\sqrt5}$. Please help.

Comment: I write it sincerely. I write in sense of ratio...If it hurts your eye you can think the last ratio as $z=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, and the exercise book is wrong.

When I follow the steps in the [article you linked](http://mathinsight.org/directional_derivative_gradient_examples) (which appears not to have your exact problem statement), I arrive at your answer as well.

Answer (score 4):

One can just do it directly, the unit vector in your direction is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(2,1,0)$

So we have $(x,y,z)=(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}t,1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}t,1)$

and $x^2+y^2+z^2=t^2+\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}t+3$

So we must differentiate

$$\ln \left(t^2+\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}t+3\right)$$ at zero, 
the derivative is

$$\frac{2t+\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}}{t^2+\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}t+3}$$

and when $t=0$ we get

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$$

So basically you are right and all those other people are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're answer is correct:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

$P = (3,2,1)$, 
$P_0 = (1,1,1)$

$\nabla f$ at $P = \left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\right)$

Indeed the unit vector in the direction of $P$ from $P_0$ is given by:
$\vec{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(P-P_0)$

So the directional derivative at $P_0$ in the direction $P$ is

$\nabla f \cdot \vec{n} = \frac{2\cdot 2 + 1\cdot 2 }{3 \sqrt{5}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$